Is it an offence to photograph a seahorse?
Britain is about to undertake a mass sea-grass survey and BSAC have released this guidance on what to do if you see a sea horse.
This paragraph stood out to me:

If you take a photo DO NOT put it on social media - it is an offence. Keep your finding quiet, just you and your dive team, not the public at large

Now, I find it hard to believe that it's an offence to take a picture of a sea horse that you stumbled across by accident, even if you need a license to actively search for them.
Is this really accurate?

Not in a position to check if this is the case, but: the use of "If you take a photo" suggests they have no fundamental problem with taking photos, but "DO NOT put it on social media" suggests they do not want (the location?) publicising, presumably to stop others coming to the same place and possibly causing damage to the environment, or disturbing the seahorses.

@TripeHound - Ahh see, I read that as "we're not going to tell you not to take a photo, but it is an offense, so don't grass on yourself"

No, I read that as don’t publish the photo. You’re over-interpreting this.

Isn't a criminal act in the UK an offence?

@MichaelHarvey - The internet has ruined me...

From the context, it isn't clear if offense is being used to mean an offense against the law of the land or an offense against the rules of this particular society.

The Seahorse Trust states on their conservation page

In 2008 both British species of seahorse became protected as named species under the Wildlife and Countryside Act (1981). . .
Another achievement, in 2010, was the banning of the use of flash photography when photographing seahorses.  This was banned on welfare grounds. After 41 years of experience we knew for certain that flash photography is harmful and kills seahorses.
It is now illegal to kill, take or disturb seahorses in British waters.

Presumably if you are close enough to photograph a seahorse, then you will be disturbing it (even without a flash), when you should be quietly leaving its vicinity, and that your business with them is only legal if you hold a licence to study them.
The Wildlife and Countryside Act uses the phrasing

intentionally or recklessly disturbs

If you accidentally disturb one, that is not an offence, but to continue to disturb it (by taking a photograph) could be considered to be intentional.

So strictly speaking if you're taking a photo, without flash, from a reasonable distance, you're probably fine?

No, I would say you are not fine, because your very presence is disturbing the seahorse. Their mortality rate from being stressed is very high. The page you linked contains advice of what to do when you find one accidentally. Put the protected seahorse above your desire to take a photo. If you take a photo you are studying it, which you need a licence for. The remark about posting on social media may be due to it possibily being an offence to publicise the location of the protected species (although I can't find it in the Act).

I don't do photography when I'm diving, got no interest in it. I'm just wondering what the legal situation is because the statement took me by surprise. I'm also somewhat skeptical that being several metres away would qualify as disturbing them...

That's human-centered thinking. Remember how much bigger you are than a seahorse. Probably larger than whatever preys on seahorses.

I think the point of being a protected species is so people don't say "but is it ok to invade their space just a little bit?" They are protected by law and you might be harming the last one in the region. Suppose they are more sensitive than you imagine, and you kill it. Would you expect the law to be sympathetic to you?

So the offense is being near them in the first place, not taking the photograph. The photograph is just evidence that they could use against you.

@ShawnV.Wilson Even if the seahorses don't feel threatened by a human's size, they are ambush predators of small crustaceans and need to eat constantly to survive. Human presence might scare off the prey species long enough to have an effect.

@ScottishTapWater I'm sure if I put an alligator/lion/bear a few meters away from you that doesn't count as disturbing you, right? Right?!

@ShawnV.Wilson: I like that way of thinking of it. A very large seahorse might be 30 cm (~1 foot) long. A human is roughly six times that tall. If you're ten times their height away from them (three meters/10 feet), and six times their size, it's roughly equivalent to a human being 18 meters/60 feet away from a giant standing 11 meters/36 feet tall. I'd be pretty intimidated by that. For smaller seahorses, the distance might increase by a factor of 10, but then, so would the height. Still scared of the 360 ft giant even if they are a tenth of a mile away. :-)

@DonQuiKong even 100m away would be scary.

@WeatherVane: Given that, if you do spot a seahorse, they actually want you to report where it was found to the Seahorse Trust (Who presumably do have a license to photograph seahorses, but that's besides the point), it may not be about publicizing the location, and more about publicizing that you committed an offence. So the guideline reads almost as a "Don't record yourself committing crimes and post it for prosecutors to see." type of guidance.

@AlexanderThe1st The Seahorse Trust, however noble their aims, have no business advising people how to behave around seahorses, which as they boast, their efforts have made a protected species. If, as they advise, you record every detail of the seahorse you saw, then you are studying it, which needs a licence.

@WeatherVane: Except upon re-reading it, it's the BSAC who want you to report it to the Seahorse Trust - and the BSAC who's specifically trying to get people to survey the seagrass. The BSAC Seagrass Survey specifically isn't giving you a license to study the seahorse, they're hedging on "If you see a seahorse accidentally while surveying the seagrass, it'd be preferred that you do not take a picture. If you do take a picture, don't take one with flash, and definitively don't post it online. Do let the Seahorse Trust know that you encountered one in that seabed with no photo."

@WeatherVane: Or to put it another way; the BSAC wants you to report the GPS location of the seahorse to the Seahorse Trust, but does not want you specifically studying the seahorse as they aren't granting you a license to do that.

@AlexanderThe1st The Seahorse Trust does say "If you see Seahorses in the wild, please let us know, we need to know everything you can tell us about them such as size, distinguishing marks, species, the habitat it was found in, was it male or female, weather conditions and depth, in fact everything you can think of." That sounds like advice to study them.

@WeatherVane: It does sound like that, to some extent - but that's why the BSAC says that the maximum to remain still and watch is five minutes. That is, without using a camera, to try and identify those details to remember for later.
While the Seahorse Trust does have an option in their form to provide an image, it sounds like they advised the BSAC that photos are not necessary, and without a license, people should try to avoid doing longer than 5 minutes of watching. Possibly defined elsewhere as the timeframe for what counts as non-photographic "Intentionally or recklessly disturbs".

So the conclusion here is then that it is neither the taking of the photo nor the uploading to social media that constitutes an offence, but the disturbance. Say I am sitting, motionless, on the sea bed taking pictures with my 800 mm lens and a large seahorse happens to swim through my field of lens-vision 30 m/100 ft away (so I’m an immobile 11-meter/36-foot giant 180 m/600 ft away). I click the shutter and stay where I am, the sea horse swims away undisturbed. Later, I scrub the GPS/EXIF data and upload the photo to social media (untagged). No offence will have been committed.

It's quite possible that the BSAC advice to not share your (non-flash!) photos is at least partly to avoid accusations of inciting the criminal act of disturbance.  I'm a caver, not a diver, and we have very similar advice regarding bats (of which all native species are protected IIRC): if you encounter any, don't photograph them and don't shine any light in their direction, then move away as soon as reasonably possible.

@TobySpeight as far as I know The Countryside Act doesn't explictly forbid revealing the location of a protected species, but if it attracts people who themselves cause a disturbance, or worse, it is feasible they could implicted.

@WeatherVane, that's what I was thinking - the disturbance is the offence, and there's a risk that one could be accused of something akin to incitement if one said - or implied - "I've been looking at seahorses and you should too".

@TobySpeight it may not even be necessary to reveal the location: if I post a photo of a Throated Widget on my family Facebook page and they all know where I go every day to have seen it, and my nephew then harms it, that was my doing.

I think that all the comments do not take into account the challenges of underwater photography. A clear signal is that the comment by@JanusBahsJacquet took many upvotes. There is no way to get a picture of a tiny seahorse from a distance. The result would always show a fuzzy undistinguishable subject. If you have a picture of a seahorse where the subject is clearly visible you must have taken it from a distance of less than two metres.

From cell phones' cameras I infer the point is not only taking the picture (as in to get the visible data you see when looking on a print), but all the meta data about the parameters about the recording including date, time, and geolocation known as exif data easily transmitted and readout by numerous programs.
An accidental geotagging by taking a photo already can be problematic for humans at land; a legal constrain on who is allowed to record such photos in order to prevent unwanted "visits" by others to protect endangered species thus doesn't appear strange.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Buttonwood, can you cite a specific law that criminalises publishing of protected animals' locations?  I'm not aware of one.

I'm not convinced by this answer, @TobySpeight , but the existence of the "Confidential Badger Report" in planning guidance wouldn't make it so surprising (though my money is on the other answer). I don't know of its legal footing, but Confidential Badger Reports an official policy aimed at not revealing the location of protected animals, and a very frequently required and well-known official procedure in a process where most documents are open.

To publish a location may be "a good", to prevent this (for ever and all, or with a temporal embargo similar to a freedom of information act, or some geographic fuzziness, or only certain to professionals [e.g. rangers]) an other. Between a plaintiff and defendant, a court might settle which is of higher value per se, for instance "protection of animals" (and hence the embargo) as more important, than the interest of an individual (who perhaps doesn't own / isn't entrusted to manage the land/the sea/the territory in question).
